# Mass delete publications in Tridion 2009

Tags: tridion

Is there a way to mass delete publications rather than delete them from the Content Manager?  I need to get rid of about 75 pubs which are now surplus.

Comment: Select all publications, right-click, delete? It will obviously do all the checks before it deletes them, but it gets the job done...

Comment: Out of interest, you are deleting 75, how many are you left with?

Comment: I faced a situation where I needed to remove 90+% of the publications. I opted to Content Port (in many pieces, but relativity painless) the ones I wanted to a new BluePrint. This also allowed me to create the optimum BluePrint.

Comment: 75 gone, 210 left.  This was never done due to performance constraints.  For example executing the purge tool on the DB took 2 weeks of continuous execution on the box I had.  In the end it was decided to leave the BluePrint structure as it was to save time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst it *may* be possible to manipulate the database directly, the only *supported* ways to delete publications is through the Content Manager or an API (although quickly looking at the documentation I think it's only possible through the older TOM API, not TOM.Net).

As Nuno suggests, for 75 publications, it will likely be far easier to do it through the Content Manager rather than write/test/debug a tool that uses the API to do the same job.

Remember that you can only delete publications as long as:

- No content in the Publication is published.
- The Publication does not have any Child Publications in a BluePrint.
- You are a system administrator.

Comment: Thanks David.  Unfortunately two of the three criteria you mention are failed by my scenario (namely the first two).  In the end, as it's a development machine I decided to manipulate the DB to set the publish/item states manually.  I'll figure out the BP manually and then do what Nuno suggested. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is using the Core Service API I would say, just call `client.Delete("tcm:0-xyz-1");` creating your Core Service Client as described on [tridion-practice](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile) for example.

However you will most likely get an `Item is in use.` error back which you probably best can resolve manually in the UI. Unpublishing the entire publication as a preparation before calling Delete is also possible using the `client.UnPublish()` method (see API documentation for details about the parameters required).

Comment: Core service only available from SDL Tridion 2011 onwards though

Answer (score 1):

A lot will depend on which publications you need to get rid of. It's easy enough to delete publications from a script. (My favourite approach is using Windows Powershell), but you'll need to delete the blueprint children first, before attempting to delete their parents. If a publication has a blueprinting child, you can't delete it.

So first figure out the blueprinting relationships, and then do the deleting. Still, for 75 publications, you would probably be finished doing it by hand before you had your script tested. Of course, if you need to transmit the same changes accurately through your DTAP street, a script is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit time taking process I deleted more than 50 last year with thousand of published item in those publication.

FYI there is quicker way to set all item as unpublished using power tool but again that will left many entries in broker db.

So it is advisable to plan this and do proper un-publishing and delete from content manager, tom API or core service.

Comment: cheers, the power tools are completely broken (not figured out why yet) - resorted to old-fashioned brute force DB edit!

Comment: Powertools selectively work if you directly access the URL rather than the going to the powertools homepage. Lasttime when I checked this one is still working. you directly go to `/Powertools/UnpublishAllCPsFromPublication.asp` and it works. Same for page unpublish as well.